# How do I make it so I can read a text file for only specific words?

Tags: python, regex, text-files, word-count

How do I get my code to only read for specific words in a text file and display the word and the count (number of times word appears in text file)?

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def openfile(filename):
 fh = open(filename, "r+")
 str = fh.read()
 fh.close()
 return str

def removegarbage(str):
 str = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str)
 str = str.lower()
 return str

def getwordbins(words):
 cnt = Counter()
 for word in words:
    cnt[word] += 1
 return cnt

 def main(filename, topwords):
   txt = openfile(filename)
   txt = removegarbage(txt)
   words = txt.split(' ')
   bins = getwordbins(words)
   for key, value in bins.most_common(topwords):
    print key,value

  main('filename.txt', 10)
```

Comment: You need a list of which words to keep a count for, and only add if the input word is on that list. As an optimization, you could initialize the `cnt` dictionary to have a zero count for each "interesting" word, and then in the main loop only increment if the word already has a count.

Comment: [Please use consistent indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). But anyway, I don't understand the problem. What isn't your code doing that you want it to do? What is it doing that you don't want it to do? What do you mean by "only read for specific words"? You can't tell if the word you're about to read is on the "specific words" list until you look at it, i.e. read it.

Answer (score 1):

i think doing that many functions is too complex, why not do it in a single function?

```
# def function if desired
# you may have the filepath/specific words etc as parameters

 f = open("filename.txt")
 counter=0
 for line in f:
     # you can remove punctuation, translate them to spaces,
     # now any interesting words will be surrounded by spaces and
     # you can detect them
     line = line.translate(maketrans(".,!? ","     "))
     words = line.split() # splits on any number of whitespaces
     for word in words:
         if word == specificword:
             # of use a list of specific words: 
             # if word in specificwordlist:
             counter+=1
             print word
             # you could also append the words to some list, 
             # create a dictionary etc
 f.close()
```

Comment: re: use of `line.split(" ")` -- Don't forget, words can be separated my far more than a single space.  There can be two spaces, three spaces, a new line, the mind boggles at the possibilities....

Comment: oh, correct. i added a translation to translate punctuation into spaces. To ignore the number of spaces i now use line.split(), which splits on any number of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A generator that yields all words in file comes in handy:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def words(filename):
    regex = re.compile(r'\w+')
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in regex.findall(line):
                yield word.lower()
```

Then, either:

```
wordcount = Counter(words('filename.txt'))               
for word in ['foo', 'bar']:
    print word, wordcount[word]
```

or

```
words_to_count = set(['foo', 'bar'])
wordcount = Counter(word for word in words('filename.txt') 
                    if word in words_to_count)               
print wordcount.items()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is an simple dictionary structure. This will let you not only keep track of the words you're looking for, but their counts as well.

A dictionary stores a things as key/value pairs. So, for instance, you can have the key "alice" (a word you want to find, and set it's value to the number of times your found that keyword.

The easiest way to check if something is in your dictionary is via Python's `in` keyword. i.e.

```
if 'pie' in words_in_my_dict: do something
```

With that information out of the way, setting up a word counter is pretty easy!

```
def get_word_counts(words_to_count, filename):
    words = filename.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if word in words_to_count:
            words_to_count[word] += 1
    return words_to_count

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fake_file_contents = (
        "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland (commonly shortened to "
        "Alice in Wonderland) is an 1865 novel written by English"
        " author Charles Lutwidge Dodgson under the pseudonym Lewis"
        " Carroll.[1] It tells of a girl named Alice who falls "
        "down a rabbit hole into a fantasy world populated by peculiar,"
        " anthropomorphic creatures. The tale plays with logic, giving "
        "the story lasting popularity with adults as well as children."
        "[2] It is considered to be one of the best examples of the literary "
        "nonsense genre,[2][3] and its narrative course and structure, "
        "characters and imagery have been enormously influential[3] in "
        "both popular culture and literature, especially in the fantasy genre."
        )

    words_to_count = {
        'alice' : 0,
        'and' : 0,
        'the' : 0
        }

    print get_word_counts(words_to_count, fake_file_contents)
```

This gives the output:

```
{'and': 4, 'the': 5, 'alice': 0}
```

Since the `dictionary` stores both the words we want to count *and* the times they've appeared. The whole algorithm is simply checking if each word is in the `dict`, and if it turns out that we is, we add `1` to that word's value.

Read up on dictionaries [here.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

### Edit:

If you want to count all of the words, and *then* find a specific set, dictionaries are still great (and fast!) for this task.

The only change we need to make is to first check if the dictionary `key` exists, and if not, add it to the dict.

#### Example

```
def get_all_word_counts(filename):
    words = filename.split(' ')

    word_counts = {}
    for word in words: 
        if word not in word_counts:     #If not already there
            word_counts[word] = 0   # add it in.
        word_counts[word] += 1          #Increment the count accordingly
    return word_counts
```

This gives the output:

```
and : 4
shortened : 1
named : 1
popularity : 1
peculiar, : 1
be : 1
populated : 1
is : 2
(commonly : 1
nonsense : 1
an : 1
down : 1
fantasy : 2
as : 2
examples : 1
have : 1
in : 4
girl : 1
tells : 1
best : 1
adults : 1
one : 1
literary : 1
story : 1
plays : 1
falls : 1
author : 1
giving : 1
enormously : 1
been : 1
its : 1
The : 1
to : 2
written : 1
under : 1
genre,[2][3] : 1
literature, : 1
into : 1
pseudonym : 1
children.[2] : 1
imagery : 1
who : 1
influential[3] : 1
characters : 1
Alice's : 1
Dodgson : 1
Adventures : 1
Alice : 2
popular : 1
structure, : 1
1865 : 1
rabbit : 1
English : 1
Lutwidge : 1
hole : 1
Carroll.[1] : 1
with : 2
by : 2
especially : 1
a : 3
both : 1
novel : 1
anthropomorphic : 1
creatures. : 1
world : 1
course : 1
considered : 1
Lewis : 1
Charles : 1
well : 1
It : 2
tale : 1
narrative : 1
Wonderland) : 1
culture : 1
of : 3
Wonderland : 1
the : 5
genre. : 1
logic, : 1
lasting : 1
```

Note: As you can see there were a couple "misfires" when we `split(' ')` the file. Specifically, some words have an opening or closing parenthesis attached. You'll have to account for this in your file handling.. but, I leave that for you to figure out!

Comment: +1 Although I would have used a dictionary to count every word and look for the wanted ones afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

this will probably suffice ... not exactly what you asked but end result is what you want (I think)

```
interesting_words = ["ipsum","dolor"]

some_text = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec viverra consectetur sapien, sed posuere sem rhoncus quis. Mauris sit amet ligula et nulla ultrices commodo sed sit amet odio. Nullam vel lobortis nunc. Donec semper sem ut est convallis posuere adipiscing eros lobortis. Nullam tempus rutrum nulla vitae pretium. Proin ut neque id nisi semper faucibus. Sed sodales magna faucibus lacus tristique ornare.
"""

d = Counter(some_text.split())
final_list = filter(lambda item:item[0] in interesting_words,d.items())
```

however its complexity is not awesome so it might take a while on big files and/or big lists of "interesting_words"